# Whether I can use the JavaScript WebSocket to connect the Python Server?

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, websocket

I use the Python written the socket server as bellow:

```
 with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
```

and I also written a Python socket client to access it:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
```

it works fine.

but now I want to use JavaScript to write a script to connect the Python socket server.

```
var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:65432")
```

I don't know how to realize it, I only know the WebSocket in the JavaScript, I don't know whether it can connect the Python's socket server.

Comment: You need to use websockets library in Python, websockets don't connect to normal sockets on the server, it's completely different API.

Comment: Like jcubic said, the Python socket library is not a websocket but a TCP server socket. You'd need a python websocket library to do it. There's more about it in this other StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553638/connect-javascript-client-to-python-websocket-server