# error when trying to connect to python socket using websocket javascript client

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, websocket

I am trying to make a connection from my javascript client in a browser to my python server and to send data from the server to the client, but when trying to connect I get the error: `failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I tried using `wss` instead of `ws`.
I also tried using `socket.io` instead of `websocket`, which wasn't helping either. I don't remember all the things I tried but none of them helped.

Javascript client:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:2001');
    conn.onmessage = function (event) {
     console.log(event.data);
```

Python server:

```
# Echo server program
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 2001 
def sendSensorData(data):

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind(HOST, PORT)
        s.listen(1)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            while True:
                print(data)
                message = str(data).encode()
                try:
                # if not data: break
                    conn.sendall(message)
                except BaseException as e:
                    print (e)
```

Edit: This is the error from python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/joep/Documents/GitHub/Walnut-installation-web-app/testAPI/workers/sensorStream.py", line 26, in sensorStream
    sendSensorData.sendSensorData(data)
  File "/Users/joep/Documents/GitHub/Walnut-installation-web-app/testAPI/functions/sendSensorData.py", line 19, in sendSensorData
    conn.send(message)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Hopefully it is a simple trick to fix it.

Comment: Which Python version is this? Since 2.0, [`socket.bind()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html#socket.socket.bind) no longer accepts a pair of parameters, only a tuple; `s.bind((HOST, PORT))`

Comment: I am using python3.7

Comment: Then you should try to pass a tuple to `s.bind()` :) Also, note that there is a dedicated [WebSockets](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) package available for Python that wraps a high-level API around the low-level socket interface, implements the websockets protocol and provides asyncio-based concurrency out of the box.

Comment: I have seen that package, but the problem is that it is using asyncio, and I am running a few thread, and as far as I know, those two aren't that great at working at the same time.

Comment: I have edited the question with the error from python

Comment: So a basic connection is established. Your client disconnects before the server starts sending the data, likely due to a protocol mismatch (server operates on TCP protocol, client attempts a handshake via websockets protocol). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48553735/4134674) answer to a similar question explains this quite nicely.

Comment: That makes sense, but as I said, I can't make asyncio work next to a running thread

Comment: There's also some thread-based websocket server packages around, e.g. [python-websocket-server](https://github.com/Pithikos/python-websocket-server) and [simple-websocket-server](https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server). Otherwise, you'll have to implement the websockets protocol on your server. Certainly not the simple trick you were hoping for, I'm afraid :/